# traversing web with user input in Android

Tags: java, javascript, android, web-services

Im fairly new to android dev and I want to build an app that basically uses a user's area code, and searches nearby safeway locations for deals on a user specified item. I believe this requires a bit of datamining or manipulating javascript found with inspect element, But I just dont know how to approach this.

Thanks, Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless they provide an API (highly unlikely), you are going to have to parse their website. Typically the first step is to find out if you can build a URL to a page that has the necessary data. For example, you might find that their site is organized with pages like this:

```
example.com/nearby-location/12345/
example.com/nearby-location/<area code here>/
```

Or something like that. From there, you can use a variety of libraries to parse that page.

My personal choice for HTML parsing on Android is Jsoup. It's fairly small, it's easy to integrate with Android, it's easy to use, and it works.

http://jsoup.org/

That said, there are a million other possible HTML parsing libraries and they all pretty much do the same thing.

Comment: Alright thanks for the advice! I just did a bunch of research on uses of Jsoup and coding examples but I frustratingly cant figure out how to tie it to my android platform... After downloading the Jsoup jar file where do I put it / how do I call it ? import..? sorry for the noobiness haha

Comment: You can import the JAR just like any other JAR files: http://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/cps004g/fall05/assign/final/addlibrary.html

Comment: Hey man. So Ive got the basics of jsoup working. Basically, I need to parse a storeID out of a page with links to various safeway locations. I want to parse the ID of the store closest in location on the page. This HTML from inspect element yielded this:

Comment: I need to parse the StoreID=970 but I have no idea how. That url actually exists as a function call within the HTML but its what I need... how do I access it? Right now i have doc.select(div #id) but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this until now. So you're trying to extract the store ID from the URL? If so, how are you getting the URL?

Comment: it turns out the site has software blocking parsing apis. thanks anyway though haha